# Save and update json data from this URL into laravel database project every 15 minute

Tags: php, laravel

I want to save these values into a database.
At the moment, it save only 1 record, the first one. However, I want it to save each one. it's quite complicate for me cause there are some arrays and objects.

Here is my code to create / update data from the link: Any help will be appreciate, I got ErrorException  : Array to string conversion.

```
<?php
$responses= file_get_contents('https://app.pyber.nl/export/objects/642e92efb79421734881b53e1e1b18b6');
$responses = json_decode($responses);
foreach($responses as $response){
    $object = Objects::create([
        'agency_id' => $agency->id,
        'user_id' => $agency->user_id,
        'category' => $response->category,
        'category_rename' => $response->category_rename,
        'neighborhood' => $response->neighborhood,
        'archived' => $response->archived,
        'type' => $response->type,
        'subtype' => $response->subtype,
        'build_year' => $response->build_year,
        'build_period' => $response->build_period,
        'living_space' => $response->living_space,
        'plot_surface' => $response->plot_surface,
        'volume' => $response->volume,
        'rooms' => $response->rooms,
        'bedrooms' => $response->bedrooms,
        'bathrooms' => $response->bathrooms,
        'status' => $response->status,
        'service_costs' => $response->service_costs,
        'new_construction' => $response->new_construction,
        'holiday_rental' => $response->holiday_rental,
        'pets_allowed' => $response->pets_allowed,
        'gated_community' => $response->gated_community,
        'featureFacilities' => json_encode($response->featureFacilities),
        'locations' => json_encode($response->locations),
        'views' => json_encode($response->views),
        'land_registries' => json_encode($response->land_registries),
        'open_house_dates' => json_encode($response->open_house_dates),
        'acceptance' => $response->acceptance,
        'price' => $response->price,
        'condition' => $response->condition,
        'address' => $response->address,
        'street_address' => $response->street_address,
        'zip' => $response->zip,
        'city' => $response->city,
        'country' => $response->country,
        'latitude' => $response->latitude,
        'longitude' => $response->longitude,
        'open_house' => $response->open_house,
        'investment' => $response->investment,
        'registration_type' => $response->registration_type,
        'sale' => $response->sale,
        'rent' => $response->rent,
        'description_nl' => $response->description_nl,
        'description_en' => $response->description_en,
        'living_styles' => json_encode($response->living_styles),
        'image' => $response->image,
        'images' => json_encode($response->images),
        'plans' => json_encode($response->plans),
        'videos' => json_encode($response->videos),
        'specialities' => json_encode($response->specialities),
        'external_plans' => $response->external_plans,
        'external_panoramas' => $response->external_panoramas,
        'titles' => json_encode($response->titles),
        'meta_keywords' => json_encode($response->meta_keywords),
        'meta_descriptions' => json_encode($response->meta_descriptions),
        'custom_urls' => json_encode($response->custom_urls),
        'custom_titles' => json_encode($response->custom_titles),
        'custom_keywords' => json_encode($response->custom_keywords),
        'custom_descriptions' => json_encode($response->custom_descriptions),
        'parking_facilities' => json_encode($response->parking_facilities),
        'price_specification' => $response->price_specification,
        'price_type_sale' => $response->price_type_sale,
        'parking_capacity' => $response->parking_capacity,
        'roof' => $response->roof,
        'roof_material' => $response->roof_material,
        'acceptance_date' => property_exists($response, 'acceptance_date') ? $response->acceptance_date : null,
        'price_type_rent' => property_exists($response, 'price_type_rent') ? $response->price_type_rent : null,
        'available_from' => property_exists($response, 'available_from') ? $response->available_from : null,
        'rented_till' => property_exists($response, 'rented_till') ? $response->rented_till : null,
        'min_contract_length' => property_exists($response, 'min_contract_length') ? $response->min_contract_length : null,
        'contract_length' => property_exists($response, 'contract_length') ? $response->contract_length : null,
        'rent_includes' => property_exists($response, 'rent_includes') ? $response->rent_includes : null,
        'rental_price_specification' => property_exists($response, 'rental_price_specification') ? $response->rental_price_specification : null,
        'renter_costs' => property_exists($response, 'renter_costs') ? $response->renter_costs : null,
        'deposit' => property_exists($response, 'deposit') ? $response->deposit : null,
        'availability' => property_exists($response, 'availability') ? $response->availability : null,
        'rental_price' => property_exists($response, 'rental_price') ? $response->rental_price : null,
        'rental_condition' => property_exists($response, 'rental_condition') ? $response->rental_condition : null,
        'panorama_viewer' => property_exists($response, 'panorama_viewer') ? $response->panorama_viewer : null,
        'garden' => property_exists($response, 'garden') ? $response->garden : '',
        'garden_quality' => property_exists($response, 'garden_quality') ? $response->garden_quality : null,
        'garden_total_surface' => property_exists($response, 'garden_total_surface') ? $response->garden_total_surface : null,
        'garden_position' => property_exists($response, 'garden_position') ? $response->garden_position : null,
        'garden_length' => property_exists($response, 'garden_length') ? $response->garden_length : null,
        'garden_width' => property_exists($response, 'garden_width') ? $response->garden_width : null,
        'garden_surface' => property_exists($response, 'garden_surface') ? $response->garden_surface : null,
        'storage' => property_exists($response, 'storage') ? $response->storage : null,
        'storage_total_amount' => property_exists($response, 'storage_total_amount') ? $response->storage_total_amount : null,
        'storage_facilities' => property_exists($response, 'storage_facilities') ? $response->storage_facilities : null,
        'storage_insulation' => property_exists($response, 'storage_insulation') ? $response->storage_insulation : null,
        'garage' => property_exists($response, 'garage') ? $response->garage : null,
        'garage_capacity' => property_exists($response, 'garage_capacity') ? $response->garage_capacity : null,
        'garage_total_amount' => property_exists($response, 'garage_total_amount') ? $response->garage_total_amount : null,
        'garage_length' => property_exists($response, 'garage_length') ? $response->garage_length : null,
        'garage_width' => property_exists($response, 'garage_width') ? $response->garage_width : null,
        'garage_surface' => property_exists($response, 'garage_surface') ? $response->garage_surface : null,
        'garage_services' => property_exists($response, 'garage_services') ? $response->garage_services : null,
        'garage_insulation' => property_exists($response, 'garage_insulation') ? $response->garage_insulation : null,
        'short_description' => property_exists($response, 'short_description') ? $response->short_description : null,
        'leaflet_text' => property_exists($response, 'leaflet_text') ? $response->leaflet_text : null,
        'usps' => property_exists($response, 'usps') ? $response->usps : null,
    ]);
}
```

My Objects model have this:

```
    protected $casts = [
    'featureFacilities' => 'array',
    'land_registries' => 'array',
    'featureFacilities' => 'array',
    'locations' => 'array',
    'views' => 'array',
    'open_house_dates' => 'array',
    'images' => 'array',
    'plans' => 'array',
    'videos' => 'array',
    'specialities' => 'array',
    'titles' => 'array',
    'meta_keywords' => 'array',
    'meta_descriptions' => 'array',
    'custom_urls' => 'array',
    'custom_titles' => 'array',
    'custom_keywords' => 'array',
    'custom_descriptions' => 'array',
    'parking_facilities' => 'array',
    'roof_material' => 'array',
];
```

Comment: Can you provide the data you're actually parsing

Comment: This is the endpoint, data come from this url: https://app.pyber.nl/export/objects/642e92efb79421734881b53e1e1b18b6

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a complex array, you need to debug it.

Does `$response->garage` syntax actually return the data?

Does it show in the error where it crashed exactly?

---

However, some things I notice with your code:

1. As a rule of thumb, never call `Model::create()` in a loop, try to write it in an array (or collection) and use `Model::insert()` to write on the database at one go.

Something like:

```
$arr = [];

foreach ($responses as $response) {
   $arr[] = [
      'agency_id' => $agency->id,
      'user_id' => $agency->user_id
   ];
}

Objects::insert($arr);
```

(With that `$arr` you can probably see what's going wrong)

2. I think this syntax `property_exists($response, 'garage') ? $response->garage : null` can be translated into `$response->garage ?? null`

Comment: Thx you @sentry if value exist it return the data, exp: $response->category inside the loop return data. Probably it crashed when it find new arrays. there are some property that have array as value.